# Weird Insert error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert

I got this error in production while executing the query I have given below

**Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.**

Query:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY

 IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Support.sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[Support]. [dbo].[ReportData]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
DROP TABLE SUPPORT.[dbo].ReportData
END

 SELECT *,CAST(NULL AS DATETIME) as LoadDate,CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(100)) AS Action
 INTO Support.[dbo].[ReportData]
 FROM dbo.ReportMain
 WHERE 1 = 0;

UPDATE mso
SET  mso.ReportStatus = '00' 
OUTPUT DELETED.*,
             @LoadDate,
             'UPDATE'
        INTO Support.dbo.ReportData
FROM dbo.ReportMain mso
INNER JOIN dbo.ReportHdr HDR
ON mso.ReportId=HDR.ReportId
WHERE mso.ReportStatus IN ('02','29')

COMMIT;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

ROLLBACK;

PRINT 'FAILED !!!';

END CATCH
```

The table dbo.ReportMain had recently been dropped and re created in Production with some columns added and its order changed and this query was executing correctly before this modification.

Can anybody explain why this error occurred

Comment: Problem is likely to be the `SELECT * ... INTO Support.[dbo].[ReportData] FROM dbo.ReportMain` if you say column order of `ReportMain` changed, but the structure of `ReportData` did not change that would explain the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this script doesn't insert anything into the `ReportMain` table I'd be extremely suspicious of the use of the `*` wildcard selector, it's a bit reckless to do that when using `select...into` or `output`. As one of the comments state, because the columns of `ReportMain` table are not guarantee to have the same order now, use explicit column names to avoid the error, or even worse...inserting data into the wrong columns

Comment: Not sure what your first (half-) sentence means, but with the rest I can agree :)

Comment: @DrCopyPaste the first "half-sentence" is absolutely inline with the error he's getting and the information provided in the question. If you put it in context the meaning will become clearer ;)

Comment: Hm, still think it reads weird, coz it reads like OP was getting the error, `because this script doesn't insert anything into the ReportMain`, but as you establish later in your answer that is not the case, the error itself is just due to the inconsistence in column ordering.

Comment: Okay,so this error is because of the changes in column order..I thought select * into and output deleted.* on the same table should return columns in the same order.